# How to create crystal report in asp.net c# with ext.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, ext.net

I want to create `crystal-report` in `asp.net` `c#`,but  with ext.net?

Is there any link/resource to which shows steps to create crystal reports?

Comment: Similar kind of question can be found. Try you can find anything from here **http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?16689-Crystal-Report-and-Ext-net**. Also good article **http://www.rahulsingla.com/blog/2011/06/ext-net-invoking-directmethods-across-aspx-pages**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just add the CrystalReport viewer Control into the  Region of any Container Type Ext.NET Component, such as Panel, Window, Container, etc.

Hope this helps.